# Hide a button until check box is checked, without ID

Tags: javascript, button, checkbox, getelementbyid

I need to hide a button until a check box is clicked, however I am stepping into someone elses code who used tag libraries that did not define ID in the button tag.  Here is what I have:

The button code:

```
<html:button name="Next" value="BTN.NEXT" styleClass="button" localeCd="<%= localeCd %>" onClick='Submit("Next")'/>
```

The checkbox code:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="fedCheck" onclick="checkFed(this, 'myNext')" value="y" />
```

The Javascript Code

```
function checkFed(ele, id) {
x = document.getElementById(id);
if (ele.checked == true) x.disabled = false;
else x.disabled = true;
```

}

I can get this to work in a seperate page but the page that it is on does not allow for the button to have an ID so it crashes every time.  Any suggestions?

Comment: I may be missing something, but it doesn't look like your button has an id.

Comment: Heh, you'll want to tag problems/questions like this with the "javascript" tag to get the right type of help, not "java".  I also suggest using a third-party site like jsfiddle.net to isolate your html, css, and javascript from your server-side code.  Often in the course of doing so you can simplify your problem and catch the problem yourself in the simpler environment.  If not, it'll be much easier for others to solve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There would be better ways of doing this, listening for the click event, etc... but, to simply modify your code see this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LvWkr/1/) (note: this assumes this is the only element named "Next"):

```
function checkFed(ele, name) {
    x = document.getElementsByName(name)[0];
    x.disabled = !x.disabled
}
```

And change the `onclick="checkFed(this, 'myNext')"` to:

`onclick="checkFed(this, 'Next')"`

And add `disabled="true"` to the button so that it's initial state is disabled

...also note that this doesn't actually hide it like the title asks, it disables it, like the content of the question seems to ask.

Comment: Well this worked so well now they want a button top and bottom of the page.  The code works with the top button, but not the bottom button. I am assuming I need some way of having the script go through all the elements, and not just the one on top.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of finding the button using document.getElementById, use document.querySelector.

For example, if you have a single button on the page with "Next" as the value of its name attribute:

```js
document.querySelector('button[name="Next"]')
```